# KineticJS : get image array id

Tags: image, html, canvas, draggable, kineticjs

Here is the problem :

I have a canvas, and four (would be more in future, but 4 for testing...anyway, doesn't matter) images that can be "poped" into the canvas by clicking on it.

Each image can be present multiple times in the canvas.

So far, poping is working fine, images are draggable... But I can't add some resize or zIndex function as I can only select the last image add to the canvas.

In a ideal world, I would like, by clicking/dragging an image, put it on top of the canvas, and kinda "select" it, so that I can connect the resize functions to the image.

But with the array of images, I can't manage to identify properly the item dragged, and can't use (or don't manage to use) the selectors.

Thank you.

EDIT : some code

```
var imgCpt = 0;
var image = [];
function addDetails(img)    {
imgCpt++;

var imageObj = new Image();
imageObj.onload = function() {
image[imgCpt] = new Kinetic.Image({
x: 0,
y: 0,
image: imageObj,
draggable: true,
id:image[imgCpt]
});

image[imgCpt].setX((stage.getWidth()/2) - (image[imgCpt].getWidth()/2));   
image[imgCpt].setY((stage.getHeight()/2) - (image[imgCpt].getHeight()/2));


eval(image[imgCpt]).on('click', function() {
alert(eval(imgCpt));
});

layer.add(image[imgCpt]);
stage.add(layer);                           
};

imageObj.src = 'uploads/'+img;
}
```

I've already tried different solutions : multiple layer, and acting on it instead of acting on image, working with shapes filled with image instead of image, but it's always the same problem : I can't get the id of the concerned element (instead of the id of the last insert element)

This version works with array, but I tried yersterday to build the image id with eval(); without more success.

Thank you for your help

EDIT² : sorry to insist, but I would really be glad to have some assistance on this point, even if I think it's more JS related than pure KineticJS related.
Thank you.

Comment: can you show some of your code? What exactly are you storing in your array? You don't need the reference to the array, you need to reference the image that's already on the canvas. Each time you create an image, you can give it an unique id, and get that id with an listener such as 'click' or something. Again, show some code, that way I'll be able to help you out more.

Comment: seems like a duplicate question... remember reading a similar question before... anyways as long as you are assigning the event handlers at the moment you are creating the object, your code should work. Another possible error could be using a temp or same variable for all the objects. Adding code could be useful for faster response

Comment: Question updated with code :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok Guys, just solved the problem :

```
eval("image["+imgCpt+"].on('click', function() {alert("+imgCpt+");});");
```

Instead of :

```
eval(image[imgCpt]).on('click', function() {
alert(eval(imgCpt));
});
```

Now time to set a true action behind the click.

Thank you for helping ;)